# docker-compose volume is not mounting properly on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am setting up docker-compose for an existing Ruby on Rails project. I am using `docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306` and `Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4`

When I am trying to start my containers for development using `docker-compose up --build` my web and worker containers are exiting with code 10. When I /bin/bash into them the /web_gen folder only contains a /tmp/db inside of that and postgres files inside of that.

I can get the containers working by changing the volumes to `- /web_gen` but then the volumes will not hot reload.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/web_gen
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  db:
    image: 'postgres:9.4.5'
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: 'bitnami/redis:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes

  worker:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -c 1
    volumes:
      - .:/web_gen
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /web_gen
WORKDIR /web_gen
COPY Gemfile /web_gen/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /web_gen/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /web_gen
```

Comment: But how do you `bash` into them if they fail to be initialized?

Comment: I can `docker-compose run web /bin/bash`. As long as it does not try to run rails server it is able to initialize. The issue is that rails server cannot start without a gemfile or .bundle which are missing

Comment: But in your `Dockerfile` you are `COPY`ing the `Gemfile` to the image. Why do you say that it is missing?

Comment: Because when I bash into the container the only things in the directory are /tmp/db/ and some postgres files